# How can i check if a given string from the user is a complex number?

Tags: python, string, list

The user is giving a string and I have to check if that number is a complex number. I tried something like that but it doesn t work if the real part or the imaginary part is greater than 9. Thanks.

```
def validation(command):
    command=command.list()
    if len(command)==3:
        if command[0]=="-" and command[1].isnumeric()==True and command[3].isnumeric()==True and command[3]=="i" and (command[2]=="+" or command[2]=="-"):
            return True

    if len(command)==4:
        if command[0].isnumeric()==True and command[2].isnumeric()==True and command[3]=="i" and (command[1]=="+" or command[1]=="-"):
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try and except` and try to convert your input to a complex number:

```
try:
    c = complex(input('enter a complex number: ')) # convert input to complex
except ValueError:
    print('you need to enter a complex number!') # failed
```

[complex](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=complex#complex) is not needed to be imported. It's a built-in:

```
>>> complex('4+5j')
(4+5j)
>>> complex('30')
(30+0j)
>>> complex('30a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string
```